# Keyboard input for a text editor

Tags: input, sdl, sdl-2

I'm making a text editor that uses OpenGL through SDL2 to render. I'm using SDL_K switch statements to get the keyboard input:

```
if (event.type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT && event.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE) {
    should_run = 0;
    break;
}
else if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
{
    switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
    {
        case SDLK_a:
        add_character(&test_element, 'a');
        break;

        case SDLK_b:
        add_character(&test_element, 'b');
        break;

        case SDLK_c:
        add_character(&test_element, 'c');
        break;

        case SDLK_d:
        add_character(&test_element, 'd');
        break;

        case SDLK_LEFT:
        move_cursor(&test_element, -1);
        break;

        case SDLK_RIGHT:
        move_cursor(&test_element, 1);
        break;

    }
}
```

For the whole keyboard, I will have two write a lot of switch cases. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Big 'ole `std::map` of `SDLK_*` enum values to `std::function`s :)  On a related note, you should tag a language & define 'better'.

Comment: @genpfault Okay I will try this, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's a better way. Use the [`SDL_TextInputEvent`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Event), which will give you the UTF-8 representation of whatever the user is typing.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I looked at the SDLKey values: https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/sdlkey.html

They are actually the ascii values of their respective characters, so I can feed event.key.keysim.sim directly into my add_character function, with an adjustment of -32 if I pressed the left shift key during the previous frame:

```
int kbshift = 0;
for (should_run = 1; should_run; ) {

    if (timer_diff > FRAME_TIME){
        timer_start = clock();

        SDL_Event event;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if (event.type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT && event.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE) {
                should_run = 0;
                break;
            }
            else if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
            {
                if (event.key.keysym.sym >= 32 && event.key.keysym.sym <= 127)
                {
                    if (kbshift)
                        add_character(&test_element, event.key.keysym.sym - 32);
                    else
                        add_character(&test_element, event.key.keysym.sym);
                }
                switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
                {
                    case SDLK_LSHIFT:
                    kbshift = 1;
                    break;

                    case SDLK_LEFT:
                    move_cursor(&test_element, -1);
                    break;

                    case SDLK_RIGHT:
                    move_cursor(&test_element, 1);
                    break;

                }
            }
            else if (event.type == SDL_KEYUP)
            {
                switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
                {
                    case SDLK_LSHIFT:
                    kbshift = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        Update();
    }

    timer_end = clock();
    timer_diff = ((double) (timer_end - timer_start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}
```

And also, thank you to HolyBlackCat. For utf-8 rendering I'll have to rethink my font texture, which is currently a 16x16 character ascii grid. A quick google search says utf-8 can support 1,112,064 unique characters. sqrt(1,112,064) = 1054.54445141, so a 1055x1055 character grid should work alright. Assuming we use all square 5x5 pixel characters, our final font texture will be of side length 1055*5 pixels--that is, our final font texture will be 5275x5275 pixels. The last thing we have to check is that 5x5px characters give us enough combinations. If our pixels can only be black or white, that's 2^25 possible 5x5px images, or 33,554,432, which is like 33 times more than what utf-8 supports. If the full 5275x5275 pixel texture is too much for the GPU to handle, I can just split it up into 2637x2637 pixel quadrants and so on.